# How can I permanently seal or cover a crack where a steam pipe enters the ceiling?

Tags: painting, pipe, crack

We're looking for a solution to cover or fix a crack that keeps reappearing around a a steam pipe we have.  No matter how well we patch it and paint over it, it keeps coming back.  Can anyone recommend a modern cover or a way to solve this issue. I have included a close-up photo below showing the crack around pipe.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your crack is forming over and over because the steam pipe is getting hot, expanding, and cracking your plaster.

The solution is to cut the plaster back about 1/4" from the walls of the pipe all the way around, then to cover the seam with an escutcheon that hides the crack.

Example of a smaller escutcheon:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Evil Greebo for the prompt reply.  Now I have the name of the proper cover (escutcheon) that I need to look for.  Any shops you think I might be able to find these? I looked on google but nothing really comes up for a diameter that big. thx

Comment: You might have to make one or have one made.  There are a number of ways you can accomplish this - for instance you could get a piece of composite (aka plastic) "shoe" molding and a heat gun and heat form it into the proper shape to fit, (with a small gap) then glue it in place with caulk to the pipe.

Comment: Cool, I will pass this onto the contractor (who I hope can figure something out)  Thx a lot once again!

Comment: Look in the plumbing dept. of your local home improvement store.You may have to ask for help finding them. There are models that have a hinge to allow you to go around the pipe and then close it.

Comment: @macutan See [this](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100343700/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=escutcheon&storeId=10051) at Home Depot. Other sizes available and should also be at Lowes and plumbing supply houses.

Comment: guys, you are awesome!  do you guys think I should ask the contractor to cut the plaster or just put the ring around it? I am guessing the cutting the plaster might help so that the crack does not extend beyond the escutcheon, no?

Comment: @macutan Yup. Per Greebo's original answer, "cut the plaster back about 1/4" from the walls of the pipe all the way around".

Comment: We are going to go with http://www.sprinklerescutcheon.com/steel-chrome-pipe-escutcheon-rings-plumbing-wallplates/

Comment: @macutan Thanks, sweet find on that one, one 4 incher on its way.

Comment: "That's what she said" ;)

Comment: good one @TheEvilGreebo

Comment: Perfect! @ Evil